# Why is NodeJS so much faster than Rust for coding Varint, according to my tests?

Tags: node.js, performance, rust, varint

I'm encoding Varint with the following two pieces of code, NodeJS takes about 900ms while Rust takes about 2700ms. Why the performance gap is so big?

It looks like allocating memory is more time-consuming, does NodeJS have any additional optimizations for allocating memory?

NodeJS version: v20.10.0

Rust version: 1.75.0

JavaScript code:

```js
// node index.js
const { performance } = require('node:perf_hooks')

function encode_varint(num) {
    let buf_size = 0;
    let cmp_number = num;

    while (cmp_number) {
        cmp_number >>>= 7
        buf_size += 1;
    }

    const buf = new Array(buf_size)
    let temp_num = num;
    let index = 0;

    while (temp_num > 0) {
        if ((temp_num >>> 7) !== 0) {
            buf[index++] = 0x80 | (temp_num & 0x7f)
            temp_num >>>= 7;
        } else {
            buf[index++] = temp_num & 0x7f
            break
        }
    }
    
    return buf;
}
const N = 100_000_000;

const start = performance.now();

for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    const num = 999_999_999_999_999;
    const buf = encode_varint(num);
    // console.log(buf)
}

const end = performance.now();
const elapsed = end - start;
console.log(elapsed);
```

Rust code:

```rust
// cargo r --release
use std::time;

fn encode_varint(num: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
    let buf_size = {
        let mut size = 1;
        let mut cmp_number = num;
        while cmp_number > 0 {
            cmp_number >>= 7;
            size += 1;
        }
        size
    };
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(buf_size);

    let mut temp_num = num;
    while temp_num > 0 {
        if (temp_num >> 7) != 0 {
            buf.push((0x80 | (temp_num & 0x7f)) as u8);
            temp_num >>= 7;
        } else {
            buf.push((temp_num & 0x7f) as u8);
            break;
        }
    }

    buf
}

const N: u32 = 100_000_000;

fn main() {

    let start = time::Instant::now();
    let num = 999_999_999_999_999;

    for _ in 0..N {
        let _buf = encode_varint(num);
        // dbg!(_buf);
    }
    
    let end = time::Instant::now();

    let elapsed = end - start;
    println!("{}", elapsed.as_millis());
}
```

Comment: The NodeJS VM probably notices that you're calling repeatedly the same code and memoizes the result after a couple of iterations, whereas Rust does the work each time. Try to use different values of `num` at each iteration (e.g. `num = 100_000_000_000_000 + i;`)

Comment: @devio there's a comment on top of each code that shows how it's called.

Comment: However I can't reproduce with Rust 1.75.0 and Node 21.5.0: I get 1090ms with Node and 17ms with Rust…

Comment: @Jmb My Rust version is “rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)”, and even I use `const num = 999_999_999_999_999 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);`, NodeJS(1280ms) is even faster than Rust(2700ms).

Comment: Note that `random` will give different results on Rust and Node since they probably use different algorithms and seeds.

Comment: I can't reproduce it too. Thats because rust sees that `_buf` is not used and totally removes the whole loop `for _ in 0..N`. And even if I make example more correct using `std::hint::black_box(encode_variant(num));` I see that rust's version is twice faster than JS.

Comment: @Dmitry to be correct you need to use `black_box` twice: `let _buf = black_box (encode_varint(num))`, at which point Rust does become slower than Node (1669ms for me). But to be correct Node should also have something to ensure that it doesn't optimize away the unused code.

Comment: @Dmitry I added `black_box` and ran the code on Win11, where NodeJS(1300ms) is 3x faster than Rust(3259ms), and on WSL, where Rust(560ms) is 2x faster than NodeJS(1301ms).

Comment: @Jmb It looks like Rust's performance on Win11 is worse than WSL's...

Comment: In the example you provided there is no difference between Win and *nix for rust. The whole loop is erased anyway. https://godbolt.org/z/EbGMj3Pvj

Comment: Hmm. Node.js - 1.5s, Golang - 2s (both on WSL)

Comment: Allocation for Node.js (V8) is definitely faster than Rust/Go, since it has compacting GC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation is not the same for two programs.
With `999_999_999_999_999` we obtain `[255, 255, 153, 166, 234, 175, 227, 1]` in Rust while we obtain `[ 255, 255, 153, 166, 10 ]` is JS.

This is due to the fact that in JS we cannot choose once for all the exact type of a numerical expression; it changes according to the operations.
For example, the initial value is quite big but stands in the mantissa of a double precision floating point (`number` type) with no loss.
The operation `>>> 7`, as all bitwise operations in JS, forces the conversion into a 32-bit integer (this is described in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift), and it was the original idea behind asm.js, which led to Wasm), then a truncation happens here in JS, while it does not in Rust.
For example, if we print the result of `temp_num >>> 7` at the beginning of each iteration in JS we see

```
NEXT 21597439
NEXT 168729
NEXT 1318
NEXT 10
NEXT 0
```

while in Rust we see

```
NEXT 7812499999999
NEXT 61035156249
NEXT 476837158
NEXT 3725290
NEXT 29103
NEXT 227
NEXT 1
NEXT 0
```

Starting from here, we cannot compare the performances of the two versions, since they are not equivalent.

On another point, and as stated in the comments, the allocation strategy is probably better in JS due to the artificially repetitive shape of this micro-benchmark (but would it still be the case on a real problem?).
`cargo flamegraph` confirms that, as most of the time is spent in allocating/freeing.
In order to improve the performance, we could make the function clear and mutate always the same vector (passed as `&mut`, created once for all in `main()`) instead of building a new one at each iteration (this would also remove the need for the computation of `buf_size`).

Comment: I changed num to 114514 and created a new array outside the loop only and tested again, the result was 280ms for NodeJS and 111ms for Rust, problem solved, thank you very much!